# Stuck on a bluetooth problem

Tags: command-line, drivers, 16.04, bluetooth, lts

I've recently installed ubuntu 16.04 LTS twice -and i discovered that the problem was from the tool katoolin so i didn't install it- after i installed ubuntu the bluetooth didn't work for me.

P.S:the bluetooth was working when my laptop was ubuntu 15.04

when i turn bluetooth on to connect my mouse the switch was on but it said that

```
Bluetooth is disabled
```

i entered the command

```
sudo rfkill unblock bluetooth
```

it worked but didn't connect to the mouse even after the next restart
i also tried to editing the file /etc/rc.local (putting sudo rfkill unblock bluetooth before last line and restarting)

and i've tried **sudo hciconfig hci0 reset** with output

> Can't init device hci0: Connection timed out (110)

my `lsusb; rfkill list` output:

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1bcf:2883 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 014: ID 04ca:3005 Lite-On Technology Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 04d9:1503 Holtek Semiconductor, Inc. Keyboard
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub


0: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
 1: asus-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
 11: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

and output of **dmesg | grep -Ei 'ath3k|blue'**

```
[    1.727681] usb 1-1.1: Product: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
[   34.157120] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.21
[   34.157135] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   34.157138] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   34.157140] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   34.157145] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   35.604410] usbcore: registered new interface driver ath3k
[   51.744300] usb 1-1.1: Product: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
[   53.810045] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x0c25 tx timeout
[   55.814079] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x0c38 tx timeout
[   57.818111] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x0c39 tx timeout
[   59.822149] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x0c05 tx timeout
[   66.997548] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   66.997552] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   66.997556] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[  195.105902] usb 1-1.1: Product: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
[  195.328480] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[  195.328488] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[  195.328495] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[  199.131870] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x1009 tx timeout
[  276.169130] usb 1-1.1: Product: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
[  294.258992] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x1005 tx timeout
[  296.263065] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x0c23 tx timeout
[  298.267076] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x0c14 tx timeout
[  306.361529] usb 1-1.1: Product: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
[  346.417970] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x0c56 tx timeout
[  348.421916] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x0c45 tx timeout
[  350.425782] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x0c58 tx timeout
[  352.429744] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x1004 tx timeout
[  366.099802] usb 1-1.1: Product: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
[  368.145218] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x1001 tx timeout
[  370.149130] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x1009 tx timeout
[  410.346611] usb 1-1.1: Product: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
[  421.612041] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x0c23 tx timeout
[  423.616060] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x0c14 tx timeout
[  425.620018] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x0c25 tx timeout
[  427.623984] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x0c38 tx timeout
[  442.650168] usb 1-1.1: Product: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
[  444.727752] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x0c52 tx timeout
[  446.731800] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x0c45 tx timeout
[  448.735743] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x0c58 tx timeout
[  450.739762] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x1004 tx timeout
[ 4000.639722] usb 1-1.1: Product: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
[ 4011.801141] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x2002 tx timeout
[ 4013.805106] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x2003 tx timeout
[ 4015.809139] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x201c tx timeout
[ 4017.813098] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x1002 tx timeout
[ 4019.817109] Bluetooth: hci0 command tx timeout
[ 4031.611130] usb 1-1.1: Product: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
[ 4073.072544] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x0c39 tx timeout
[ 4075.076588] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x0c05 tx timeout
[ 4077.080593] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x0c16 tx timeout
[ 4079.084502] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x2002 tx timeout
[ 4081.088484] Bluetooth: hci0 command tx timeout
```

I also installed blueman but useless

I would really appreciate any solution

P.S : IT SOMETIMES WORKED FOR ME AFTER TURNING BLUTOOTH ON/OFF AND ENTERING sudo rfkill unblock bluetooth
 A LOT OF TIMES

Comment: Your bluetooth adapter is Atheros, not Realtek.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post output of `lsusb; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 Done :) ...i didn't realize it's Atheros but i don't think it need driver because it worked on 15.04

Comment: This is your device `04ca:3005 Lite-On Technology Corp.`. It does not need a driver. Please also add output of `dmesg | grep -Ei 'ath3k|blue'`.

Comment: And you can format the text normally by selecting it and pressing `{}` button.

Comment: @Pilot6 i added the output

Comment: This is some kernel bug. Report it to Launchpad.

Comment: how can i report to lauchpad ?

Comment: Run `ubuntu-bug linux` and follow the instructions.

Comment: i'm thinking about downgrading to 15.04...16.04 has a lot of errors not this only :(

Comment: 15.04 is not supported.

Comment: this worked for me, I had the problem after suspend. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1387211